# onLoad IBAction SubmitB

Tags: objective-c, ios

i got a problem... i have a button.. when i click on the button, the function

```
-(IBAction)SubmitB; 
{
        self.String = textdata.text;
        NSString *nameString = String;

        NSString* AUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AUrl]];

}
```

will be activate.

It sounds dump... but i want to activate it without pressing the button... in this example you click on a button and the textfield sends the data to the String variable... but he have to send the data if the app is loaded

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by you "want to load" the funtion? Please describe your problemmore verbose...

Comment: i edited my question.. hope you understand my problem now

Answer (score 0):

... well from what I understand, why don't you put your code into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? Something like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSString *nameString = @"whatever";

    NSString* AUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AUrl]];
}
```